# Rotate shapefile in 3d (about x-axis)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcscene, cross-section

I have a polygon shapefile which I'd like to rotate 90 degrees about the x-axis in 3d. The polygon is currently flat (projected in plan view), I'd like to project it vertically. Specifically, this is a geologic cross section currently projected with depth on the Y-axis - I want to turn the polygon into it's proper Z-orientation.

I have access to 3d-analyst and ArcScene, AutoCAD.

Answer (score 2):

I placed points along section line at regular interval:

[image]
and sampled top and bottom elevations of clay and basalt layers:
[image]

After that I ran script below twice from active mxd. Highlighted fields are the ones I used for 1st run:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

Script creates 2 near-vertical triangles using coordinates of 2 consequitive points and pairs of elevation values.

Due to smartness (is this a correct word?) of ArcGIS, I was  unable to create true vertical triangles (**which works perfectly fine in grandmother ArcView 3 environment**), because any attempt to create polygon with zero area in XY plane, results in NULL shape.
Play with parameter **fArcGIS** in the script to see how small you can make it to force ArcGIS in create polygon instead of fake shape.

On the other hand the slight horizontal shift of 0.1 m that I applied, worked fine for visual presentation of geology and I hope it is only visual thing you are after, otherwise I strongly suggest software truly capable of working with 3D geometries.

```py
 ##3D fence maker
import arcpy, sys, os,traceback
inLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
layerFld=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
roof=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
base=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
target=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
d=arcpy.Describe(inLayer)
SR=d.spatialReference
fArcGIS=0.1

try:
    def showPyMessage():
        arcpy.AddMessage(str(time.ctime()) + " - " + message)
    curT = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(target,["SHAPE@","NAME"])
    for i,row in enumerate(arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inLayer, ("SHAPE@XY",layerFld,roof,base))):
        if i==0:
            (x1,y1),lr,UpZ1,BotZ1=row
        else:
            (x2,y2),lr,UpZ2,BotZ2=row
            LL=arcpy.Point(x1,y1,BotZ1)
            UL=arcpy.Point(x1+fArcGIS,y1+fArcGIS,UpZ1)
            UR=arcpy.Point(x2,y2,UpZ2)
            pgonZ=arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([LL,UL,UR,LL]),SR,True)
            curT.insertRow((pgonZ,lr))
            LR=arcpy.Point(x2+fArcGIS,y2+fArcGIS,BotZ2)
            pgonZ=arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([LL,UR,LR,LL]),SR,True)
            curT.insertRow((pgonZ,lr))
            (x1,y1),lr,UpZ1,BotZ1=row
except:
    message = "\n*** PYTHON ERRORS *** "; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Traceback Info: " + traceback.format_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])[0]; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Error Info: " +  str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"; showPyMessage()
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your help. I haven't tried this yet, but it might be useful going forward.